# Integral of complex exponential using the residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

A question about probably some basics of the Residue Theorem but my fondations are quite shaky.

I tried calculating $$ \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{e^{iay}}{(1+iy)^2}  dy$$ using the residue theorem and all is good you find the poles, you use the upper semi circle as a contour and you finally get the value $$2 \pi a e^{-a}$$

However, when trying to compute it numerically it seems that this only holds for $a>0$ and if $a\leq0$, then the result is $0$.

I don't really understand why, and it ties to another issue I have which is it seems to me that even if $a>0$ we could use the lower semi circle and get no pole inside it and get $0$.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $a<0$, you can NOT use upper semicircle as the contour, since it is divergent. For example, if choose the upper semicircle as the contour, let $y=R\cos\theta+i R\sin\theta,~\theta\in [0, \pi]$, then

$$\lim_{R\rightarrow \infty} e^{iay}\rightarrow \infty$$

Therefore, you have to use lower semicircle as the contour, but in this case, there are no poles inside your contour. Because the only pole is $y=i$, which is located on the upper half plane. So you get $0$ for your integral when $a<0$.

Comment: Thank you! This was one of the ideas I had however I don't understand how the argument to prove that the integral goes to zero on the contour (apart from the real line) does not hold, which is that we have $$|y| = R, |\frac{e^{iay}}{(1+iy)^2}|\leq \frac{1}{(1+R)^2} $$

So, $$|\int_{C_R^+(0)} \frac{e^{iay}}{(1+iy)^2} dy|\leq \frac{\pi R}{(1+R)^2} \longrightarrow 0, \;\text{ as R } \rightarrow \infty$$

Comment: No, this is not true, because $|e^{iay}|=1$ if and only if $y\in \mathbb{R}$, but here $y=R\cos\theta+i R\sin\theta$, which is not real, so $|e^{iay}|=|e^{ia(R\cos\theta+i R\sin\theta)}|=e^{-aR\sin\theta}$, it is clear that this term diverges when $a<0$.

Comment: There was my error, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome.